# How to list all classes without test in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to list all classes without tests in IntelliJ IDEA?

if we already can,

- jump from a test and its source
- create a test for a class?

Gradle task `jacoco` helps, and it what I am using, but I still want to know if there is something built-in in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run your test suite with code coverage:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it is one way to look at it. Let us wait if anyone has other ideas about "list classes without tests, and if possible, create the same directory tree and files as `main` package in `test`".

Comment: To create files for tests, you could export the test coverage results as html-file and then use that file to run a script that creates your classes.

Comment: Oh I am not aware of the script part. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Well you'd have to write such a script yourself. Parse the html, find out which classes have a coverage of 0%, make a in that location.

Comment: Hm OK. At least I now can generate a HTML file and I find it very well organised. Thanks.

Comment: At last I think Intellij IDEA coverage HTML report should be a 80% solution.